# "Check Spelling While Typing" grayed out

Tags: xcode, spell-checking

I'm trying to spell check static strings in my code. I've searched stackoverflow with no useful results (e.g. refers to outdated version of Xcode or just no answers). I just installed the latest update of Xcode (version 9.2) and it still doesn't work (i.e., the option is grayed-out).

[image]

Comment: It's grayed out for me as well. I think that the option is disabled by default and cannot be changed.

Comment: looks like there is an issue with Xcode 9 https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/88329

Answer (score 2):

Ignore greyed out button and press CMD+; anywhere inside the code editor.
The greyed options will now be enabled.